# How can I read a pixel's color from a BitmapImage in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, pixel, bitmapimage

I have a BitmapImage instance in Silverlight, and I am trying to find a way to read the color information of each pixel in the image. How can I do this? I see that there is a `CopyPixels()` method on this class that writes pixel information into the array that you pass it, but I don't know how to read color information out of that array.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Look for the `WriteableBitmap` class in Silverlight 3. This class has a member `Pixels` which returns the bitmap's pixel data in an array of int's.

An example with a transform. `bi` is an `BitmapImage` object.

```
Image img = new Image();
img.source = bi;

img.Measure(new Size(100, 100));
img.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, 100, 100));

ScaleTransform scaleTrans = new ScaleTransform();
double scale = (double)500 / (double)Math.Max(bi.PixelHeight, bi.PixelWidth);
scaleTrans.CenterX = 0;
scaleTrans.CenterY = 0;
scaleTrans.ScaleX = scale;
scaleTrans.ScaleY = scale;

WriteableBitmap writeableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(500, 500);
writeableBitmap.Render(img, scaleTrans);

int[] pixelData = writeableBitmap.Pixels;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with the current Bitmap API in the currently released Silverlight 3 beta.

The Silverlight BitmapImage file does not have a CopyPixels method. Please see the MSDN documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage(VS.96).aspx).

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage_methods.aspx

It is on MSDN, but yes it doesn't seem to be available in Silverlight.

Comment: The link you provided is for .NET 3.5, not Silverlight.
You can find the MSDN documentation for the Silverlight BitmapImage class here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage(VS.96).aspx

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use `WritableBitmap` to get pixels collection: `WriteableBitmap bmp = new WriteableBitmap(bitmapImageObj);`. Each pixel is represented as 32-bit integer. I have made structure, which just helps to splits integer into a four bytes (ARGB).

```
struct BitmapPixel
{
    public byte A;
    public byte R;
    public byte G;
    public byte B;

    public BitmapPixel(int pixel)
        : this(BitConverter.GetBytes(pixel))
    {
    }

    public BitmapPixel(byte[] pixel)
        : this(pixel[3], pixel[2], pixel[1], pixel[0])
    {
    }

    public BitmapPixel(byte a, byte r, byte g, byte b)
    {
        this.A = a;
        this.R = r;
        this.G = g;
        this.B = b;
    }

    public int ToInt32()
    {
        byte[] pixel = new byte[4] { this.B, this.G, this.R, this.A };
        return BitConverter.ToInt32(pixel, 0);
    }
}
```

Here is an example of how it could be used to change red value:

```
BitmapPixel pixel = new BitmapPixel(bmp.Pixels[0]);
pixel.R = 255;
bmp.Pixels[0] = pixel.ToInt32();
```

Also I would like to mention that [WriteableBitmap.Pixels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.pixels%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) are in Premultiplied RGB format. [This](http://nokola.com/blog/post/2010/01/27/The-Most-Important-Silverlight-WriteableBitmap-Gotcha-Does-It-LoseChange-Colors.aspx) article will explain what it means. And here is how compensation done by using BitmapPixel structure:

```
public static void CompensateRGB(int[] pixels)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < pixels.Length; i++)
    {
        BitmapPixel pixel = new BitmapPixel(pixels[i]);

        if (pixel.A == 255 || pixel.A == 0)
            continue;

        if (pixel.R == 0 && pixel.G == 0 && pixel.B == 0)
        {
            // color is unrecoverable, get rid of this
            // pixel by making it transparent
            pixel.A = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            double factor = 255.0 / pixel.A;

            pixel.A = 255;
            pixel.R = (byte)(pixel.R * factor);
            pixel.G = (byte)(pixel.G * factor);
            pixel.B = (byte)(pixel.B * factor);
        }

        pixels[i] = pixel.ToInt32();
    }
}
```